# How does offScreenPageLimit work for viewpager

Tags: java, android

After you go out of the offScreenPageLimit, what does the system call to get a new view or page back?

Comment: to keep it simple you can do viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(10) for exemple an the fragments will be kept alive

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [source code for `ViewPager`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.java) is really the best place to find your answer.

In a nutshell, a `ViewPager` keeps an internal list of items (that respresent 'pages'). The number of items in this list is based on the the `mOffScreenPageLimit` value. By default it's set to `1`, but you can change it by calling `setOffscreenPageLimit(int limit)`.

In the (package protected) method `populate()`, which is where the `ViewPager` gets populated with pages, the following code snippet is located:

```
final int pageLimit = mOffscreenPageLimit;
final int startPos = Math.max(0, mCurItem - pageLimit);
final int N = mAdapter.getCount();
final int endPos = Math.min(N-1, mCurItem + pageLimit);
```

That determines the bounds of the dataset that backs the `PagerAdapter` and hence which positions pages will be requested for.

Non-existing pages are created using the (package protected) `addNewItem()` method, which basically ends up calling `instatiateItem()` on the associated `PagerAdapter`. This is the part you usually implement, either directly or through one of the concrete subclasses.

If something changes along the way, i.e. when the backing dataset is changed, or when `setOffscreenPageLimit()` is called again with a different value, items may be removed from the internal list, and a call `destroyItem()` on the `PagerAdapter` usually follows.

Does that answer your question? If not, try to be a bit more specific than a one-liner - that should help us to better help you. :)